# Efficient data structure for storing timestamp data & calculating in a rolling window

Tags: python, data-structures, moving-average

I have a large Twitter data stream, and I am interested in analyzing the relationships of hashtags in each tweet. For example, if hashtag A and hashtag B appear in the same tweet, I would record this tweet as "A-B" together with the timestamp of the tweet.

As such, sample inputs are:

```bash
hashtags,       Timestamp 
A-B,     created_time: 2016-04-07T01:33:19Z 
B-C,     created_time: 2016-04-07T03:53:19Z 
C,       created_time: 2016-04-08T03:31:19Z
C-A,     created_time: 2016-04-08T04:33:19Z 
A-D,     created_time: 2016-04-07T07:33:19Z  # (Note: an example of out of order)
B-D,     created_time: 2016-04-09T09:33:19Z
```

Note that the stream data might not be ordered by time.

Tasks: 
1) Use the stream data to build a graph of hashtags (A, B, C, C...) and their relationship with one another.
2) Calculate the average degree of a vertex in a graph and update this each time a new stream data appears (across a one-day sliding window).

The average degree of a vertex is defined as: degree = number of edges/number of nodes. For example, if the current graph is A-B, then the average degree = 1(edge)/2 (# of nodes).

Sample outputs:

```
Output
1/2,
2/3,
1/2,
1/2,
2/3,
1/2
```

What is the most efficient Python data structure to store a such timestamp data in order to calculate the average degree of vertex in a one-day rolling window?*

My intuition is to use a dictionary to store and maintain the hashtags as key, and the `created_time` as values. So in order to maintain a one-day window, I need to first sort the dictionary, which takes lots of time. Is there a more efficient way to automatically store the timestamp data based on time (no need for sort)?

I found posts using the Pandas `DataFrame` and rolling functions to do the similar tasks. But in my case, I am looking for a most efficient *data structure* to do the task.

Updates:
After more research about my question, I found this question is a good match to mine. 
[Ideal data structure with fast lookup, fast update and easy comparison/sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19276592/ideal-data-structure-with-fast-lookup-fast-update-and-easy-comparison-sorting)

The key idea is to use `[heapq][2]`

Comment: What will be consuming this data once sorted? One, two, multiple processes? Perhaps a database would be appropriate.

Comment: Pandas is very efficient if all your data fits into memory - it's not clear though why do you need `rolling window` functions. Can you post desired data set?

Comment: @MaxU, and Copy and Paste, after sorted, I want to calculate the average degree of edges and nodes in a one-day time window. The average degree of edges and nodes is defined as degree = total edges / total nodes. That is why I talked about the rolling window functions.

Answer (score 1):

The tweets can be expected to be mostly sorted, so a sequence type with [insertion sort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/220044/699305) should be a good way to get them ordered. Add a rolling window to replace the oldest ones after you reach 24 hours.

For efficient insertions, you'll want a sequence type with better insertion support than `list`. I'd give [`blist`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/?) a try. In fact it provides a `sortedlist` type, so you could try that out and see what kind of performance it achieves.

This all assumes that your stream doesn't grow too fast to keep a whole day's tweets in memory. If it does, you'll *have* to delegate to some kind of database.

Comment: You are right that this problem should be solved using an efficient insertion sort related data structure. But after an exclusive search of all the possible data structures that can do the job, I felt the python heapq should be the best one, since it can maintain insert, delete better for a stream data.

Comment: Then heapq it should be. You'll get no argument from me -- I just mentioned some options I've heard of.

Answer (score 1):

I would use pandas. Here is an example implementation which sorts out timestamps based on a window. You would need to copy your data into a dataframe first.

```
import datetime
import dateutil.relativedelta

days_back = 1
datetimeFormat = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
dt_now = datetime.datetime.now()
start_date = dt_now - dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(days=days_back)
start_date = start_date.strftime(datetimeFormat)
df2 = df[df['time_stamp'] > start_date]
```

Comment: Thanks. This may work well for normal time series data operation, but not efficient enough to do a stream data.

Comment: don't see any usage of pd?

Comment: Thanks slashdottir I removed it. Pandas is necessary to create the dataframe df.